# Grub rescue problem

Tags: boot, grubrescue

My computer won't start. All that happens is:

```
booting in insecure mode 
Failed to open  EFI/Ubuntu\Momangen.efi - not found
Failed to load image EFI/Ubuntu\Momangen.efi : not found
Error: secure boot forbids loading module from (hd0,gpt3)/boot/grund/x86_64-efi/normal.mod. 
Entering rescue mode... 
Grub rescue>
```

This will show then nothing else happens. This began after repairing Ubuntu.